# Is there a difference in break statement between C and Python?

Tags: python, c, loops, break

I'm working on a python program and i'm still a beginner in python.
i've a c program that i'm trying to write in python, i'm facing a problem because in this program, break statement isn't performing the same way.
I've a loop and then a second inner loop and if condition where i need to break if the if condition is valid.
What i need is one break statement in the if condition.
in Python using this only break statement isn't giving me correct results while in c it's working.
I noticed that in C if i put a second break in the second loop after the if condition i'm getting same wrong results i'm getting in python.

```py
for f in range(1,6):
    for k in range(1,8):
        if(x==y):
            break
    if ///// :
        break
```

```c
for (int f = 1; f < 6; f++){
    for (int k = 1; k < 8; k++){
        if(x==y)
            break;
    }
    if /////
         break
}
```

so these two codes aren't giving same result, 
while if i change c code to this one, it will give me same pythong wrong results

```c
for (int f = 1; f < 6; f++){
    for (int k = 1; k < 8; k++){
        if(x==y)
            break;
    }
    break;    <------------------------------- if i add this 
    if //////
         break;
}
```

Comment: I don't see a reason why those two code snippets would behave differently, unless your python program had an indentation issue where the interpreter thought your break statement was in the outer loop, not the inner one. I suggest you add some print statements to both pieces of code to verify the result you're getting. Also, you weren't very specific in your question about what result you saw that was different from what you were expecting. Please [edit] your question to fix that.

Comment: Also, are x and y supposed to be f and k? If not, where are they coming from? Are they being changed inside the loops?

Comment: no x and y aren't f and k, and actually it's a big program and i have results i'm waiting for, it's a cryptanalysis system that i'm trying to write in python.

Comment: You should always produce an example that is consistent: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 4):

`break` behaves the same in both languages. Check the indentation in your Python program. Your first two samples shpuld behave the same.